# Can SQL select values in one table to match a field in another table with wildcards? (Value like %value%)

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, sql

We have two tables - one is the `_click` table and the other is a catalog of `ProductIDs` and we'd like to find all the clicks from the previous day where the ProductID is in the `LinkContent` field.

The problem is the `ProductID` data is not an exact match, but is `like` the value in `LinkContent` and so I don't know how to add the wildcards to find the matches.

Example:
`LinkContent = http://www.somedomain.com/1234?utm_campaign=...`

`Value in Table ProductID is 1234`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably do it using a LIKE statement concatting the wildcards before and after the column.

e.g. `click.LinkContent LIKE '%/' + prod.ProductID + '?%'`

So full sample (with dummy fields, etc.)

```
SELECT prod.ProductID
, yourOtherFields
FROM [ProductIDs] prod
INNER JOIN [_Click] click
ON click.LinkContent LIKE '%/' + prod.ProductID + '\?%'
WHERE click.EventDate >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
```

That should get you all records in past 24 hours that has a productID (from ProductIDs DE) in between the `/` of the URL and the `?` (note the `\` in front to escape it as `?` is a wildcard character for SQL, so needs to be escaped to be literal) Query Parameter marker.  Which appears to be where the ProductID would be located in your URLs.

Comment: please add this to my tab!  I had to make a few changes (based on data type, I used a CAST) but overall this got me on the right path.  THANK YOU